# Jenkins creating jar by using my git project

Tags: jenkins

I have acreated a simple jenkins project and on build section, I use a shel bash script (execute shell) as follow:

```
cd /home/ubuntu
git clone https://github.com/Bazarganigilani/AppEngineCron.git
mvn clean install
```

However , when I built my project I face

```
+ cd /home/ubuntu
+ git clone https://github.com/Bazarganigilani/AppEngineCron.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'AppEngineCron': Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I ssh to the node having this jenkins I can git clone in my /home/ubuntu directory but not through jenkins?

Is there a better way to avoid clone and make my jar somewhere in the jenkins node?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Jenkins is running with different user (other than UBUNTU). Mostly Jenkins will run with Jenkins user. So Jenkins user may not have permissions to create directory in /home/ubuntu.

**Possible Solution:** give /home/ubuntu folder access to the user which is running Jenkins